# Visual Studio 2008 Web Project (Web Site) How to exclude a folder from the project

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a web application or web site in VS 2008. One folder gets populated with over 50 000 files during a debugging session. The problem is that it takes forever for Visual Studio to load once these folders are populated with all the files.

In a class library project I can right click and exclude from project. How is it possible to exclude a folder/directory from a web site project using Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not ideal, but you can set the folders to hidden in explorer, then they don't get loaded into Visual Studio...

Not ideal at all , because once the directories are hidden code that is writing files to these directories fail with permission errors.

Answer (score 1):

The article "*Some Techniques for Better Managing Files in Visual Studio 2005 Web Projects*" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa479565 might help you.

Comment: Figured as much. I had nearly the same problem, ended up moving the folder outside of the project.