# Is it possible to exclude folders from a web application project in vs 2010?

Tags: web-applications, visual-studio-2010

I had previously asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279006/visual-studio-2008-web-project-web-site-how-to-exclude-a-folder-from-the-projec). At the time I was working with VS 2008.

To restate the question. I have a web application that generates 1000's of small xml files in a certain directory. I would like to exclude this directory from the web application project in visual studio 2010. With vs 2008 it was not possible. Has anything changed?

Besides the general wait for VS to iterate through this directory and add an item in the solution explorer for each file, it also strains my system resources, so I would like to exclude it from the project, but the dir and files need to physically exist on disk, because they are part of the application.

Any OOB VS 2010 solutions, or any good workarounds?

Thanks

**Update:** This also sums up the issue nicely http://forums.asp.net/t/1179077.aspx

Comment: Why are the XML files included in your build? Are they content files? Can you move the directory outside your solution?

Comment: @Rohan, question updated - files are created at run time, and the populate a directory which will get loaded when the VS 2010 IDE loads that web application project.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the folder in Solution Explorer in VS 2010 click on 'Exclude From Project'...

Comment: Unfortunately that option isn't available for folders in web projects http://i.imgur.com/qddPjqr.png

Answer (score -1):

Check out this post, a modification to the project file has been introduced to exclude a specific directory from the build process. You could look at other msbuild options too

[Exclude folder from website build using MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302757/exclude-folder-from-website-build-using-msbuild)

Comment: My web site doesn't have a project file. Maybe I need to convert it to a web application first?